# Как отключить сервис MsMpEng.exe в последней Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, безопасность

Как отключить\заблокировать\удалить сервис MsMpEng.exe в Windows 10 Home (с установленными последними обновлениями)?

Comment: Штатными средствами не получается?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вообще никак. С последними обновами десятки они заблокировали эту возможность. Перерыл кучу мануалов в гугле, все бесполезно.

Comment: Может кто пробовал, я пока не могу проверить следующий способ. Установить любой антивирус, хоть Лаборатории Касперсокго или TrеndMicro.  А затем отключить антивирусные модули. Таким образом, при наличии установленного стороннего антивируса встроенный **Windows Defender** должен быть не активен. А установленный - работе мешать не будет. По хорошему, нужно внимательно диагностировать плохую работу Windows Defender или добавить в исключения некоторые файлы, чтобы снизить его нагрузку на CPU. Если этот способ "прокатит", сообщите пожалуйста.